# How do I rewrite a fake filename into a GET argument for a hidden file on nginx?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

How to turn `example.com/search.php?q=QUERY` into `example.com/s/QUERY`

So that when you visit `example.com/s/QUERY` it executes `example.com/search.php?q=QUERY`

And also how do you block access to `example.com/search.php?q=QUERY` directly or re-direct it back to `example.com/s/QUERY`?

Comment: What have you tried, what was the result. There are plenty of articles that describe this